# Fix "Docker daemon failed to start" error after (Mac) OS upgrade

Tags: macos, docker, macos-big-sur, docker-daemon

After getting numerous messages saying I should upgrade my **OS**, I have finally decided to upgrade to **macOS Big Sur** `v11.6.1`.

Unfortunately, docker doesn't work anymore.

I'm getting an error:

```
Fatal Error

Docker daemon failed to start
```

and

```
2021-12-07T09:47:14Z dockerd time="2021-12-07T09:47:14.957430297Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /version"
```

[image: docker-error]

I can see the option to **Reset Docker to factory defaults** but I'm afraid of resetting because it means I will also erase all my docker images.

Is there any easy way to fix this issue without erasing my work?

Comment: I don't know MacOS, but I do know Docker and NIX systems. See your docker desktop (or plain docker CLI) as a web client and the docker deamon as a service (a web service, actually). What you are experiencing is the former not being able to access the later. Main hypothesis: the service does not run anymore (not started automatically). How do you start a service manually on Mac? Once you know for sure that the service is running, you could go on a more dangerous path / exotic hypothesis. But not before because, for all we know, everything is still in place

Comment: The daemon doesn't seem to work. I get nothing when I try PS. If I try `docker system info` I get an error like: `ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Finally (  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/log/host/Docker.log ) something like: `time="2021-12-08T01:52:50Z" level="info" msg="Analyser: Report from failure analysis:AnalyseReport(reason: ""Docker daemon failed to start"", detail: ""2021-12-07T09:47:14Z dockerd time=\\""2021-12-07T09:47:14.957430297Z\\"" level=debug msg=\\""Calling GET /version\\"""", action: Docker.AnalyseAction.FatalError)"`

Comment: `docker system info` => your client. Still getting to the same issue, which is: find a way to launch the deamon manually. You first need to locate it. For instance, on my Ubuntu, with `find /usr -name "docker.*"`, I know that the deamon lives in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. I really do not now how services are handled on Mac but with my previous explanation, these guys might help you figure how to start your docker deamon [https://apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com). I wish I could do more

Comment: Finally ! Fixed ! I was able to fix it by downloading the Docker Desktop installer ( [docker.com/products/docker-desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) ) and selecting overwrite. I've made a backup of all images which are stored in `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data` but looks like the installation process was clever enough to keep the existing images...

Answer (score 1):

I get this fairly often on my Mac. I'm still on Big Sur.

This in the terminal seems to get me working (pay attention to the capitalisation):

```
pkill Docker
open -a /Applications/Docker.app
```